# Is it possible to define a generic extension method in F#?

Tags: f#, extension-methods

I was trying to use Rhino Mocks with F# code, and the following code was a problematic:

```
let service = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IMyService>()
service.Stub(s => s.Name).Return("Service");
```

This was no surprise, since Stub is not part of IMyService interface, it's a C# extension method that Rhino Mocks defines.

Slighltly modified code works:

```
let service = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IMyService>()
RhinoMocksExtensions.Stub<IMyService, string>(service, fun s -> s.Name).Return("Service");
```

However, it would be nice to define an extension method in F#, but then it will be a parameterized generic extension method that would take a tuple . I was trying varios syntax but without any luck. I didn't find information whether this is currently supported in F# or not. If anyone knows, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the answer is no.  [Section 8.12.1 of the spec](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc264042002) (Imported C# Extensions Members) includes this text:

> C#-defined extension members are made
>   available to F# code in environments
>   where the C#-authored assembly is
>   referenced and an open declaration of
>   the corresponding namespace is in
>   effect. However, some limitations
>   apply, notably
>
> - C# extension members whose “this”
>     parameter is a variable type are not
>     made available to F# code in this
>     version of F#
> - C# extension members whose “this”
>     parameter is an array type are not
>     made available to F# code in this
>     version of F#

This explains why some extension methods from C# will work (e.g. those in System.Linq), while the one that you are attempting to use will not.

Furthermore, native F# extension methods can only be defined as if they were placed on actual type definitions.  In particular, you can't define an F# extension method on a closed generic type (e.g. `IEnumerable<string>`) nor can you define an extension method on a generic type variable.

Answer (score 4):

As kvb mentioned, it's not possible in F# 2.0. In this particular case I'd wrap Rhino.Mocks fluent interface to make it more idiomatic in F#, e.g.:

```
let mstub f target =
    RhinoMocksExtensions.Stub(target, Function(f))

let mreturn value (options: IMethodOptions<'a>) =
    options.Return value

let service = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IComparer>()
service |> mstub (fun s -> s.Compare(1,2)) |> mreturn 1 |> ignore
```

[What's fluent in one language is not necessarily fluent in another.](http://bugsquash.blogspot.com/2009/04/using-windsor-in-f.html) (sorry for the plug but I really think it's relevant here)

Comment: Marurcio,

Thank you for the explanation. Yes, I also came to the same conclusion that such extensions that are quite useful in C# wouldn't bring that much value to F#, and there are other (and better) ways of expressing this in F#.