# Is it possible to define extension methods for parameterized generic types in F# (like in C#)

Tags: generics, f#, extension-methods

In C# I can define an extension method that applies **only to parameterized generic types**:

```
public static bool fun(this List<int> coll, int x)
{
    return coll.Contains(x);
}
```

I tried the same in F# but found no way to do so:

```
type List<'k when 'k :> int32> with
    member o.x s = o.Contains s
```

This raises
Error FS0660: *This code is less generic than required by its annotations because the explicit type variable 'k' could not be generalized. It was constrained to be 'int32'.*

It certainly is possible to define a generic extension method like

```
type List<'k> with
    member o.x s = o.Contains s
```

and on a side note to make that extension method available in C#. But that is not the question here. i am concerned about a **parameterized** generic function. Which I believe is possible to declare only in C# but not in F#.

I conclude that in C# extension methods are functions while in F# the similar concept is implemented as type extensions and parameterized generics are no types, so this is not possible.

Am I correct that there is no way to do the same in F#?

There is a similar question here: [Is it possible to define a generic extension method in F#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381570/is-it-possible-to-define-a-generic-extension-method-in-f) but since 11 years have passed I raise the topic again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

F# has a mechanism for defining extensions that is "C#-compatible", and your use case is specifically called out, check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/type-extensions#extension-methods).

Something like this should work:

```
open System.Collections.Generic
open System.Runtime.CompilerServices

[<Extension>]
type Extensions =
    [<Extension>]
    static member inline ContainsTest(xs: List<int>, s: int) = 
        xs.Contains(s)
```